# HTC One X factory resets itself

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

My HTC One X erased everything on the phone by itself. i lost everything from contacts to pictures to music, everything's gone! I have no back ups! Please, how can I restore everything back? All my important things are gone please!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if there are no backups of your device, it cannot be restored.

However you may still have some data!

If you had the app Google Photos, your photos are saved online, and can be accessed at photos.google.com.

If you had Google Drive on your phone, your files can be received on the platform on your computer.

If you had Chrome, your bookmarks are most likely synced with your computer.

If you have any questions, please respond!
Regards,
James Kerrane